# Leave blank combo box when changing focus to the other field

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I have a combo box with couple values, including a blank value.
When I select the combo box and then tab away (loose focus) my default value is replaced with the first item from the list. 
I want it to stay blank if nothing has been selected.

The code looks as follows:

```
<select data-ng-disabled="!model.AmendEnabled" data-ng-model="model.ProTitleId" data-val="true" data-val-number="Title must be a number." data-val-required="Title is required" id="ProTitleId" name="ProTitleId" tabindex="1" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Ms</option>
    <option value="3">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="4">Miss</option>
</select>
```

What actually happens after the focus is moved to the other field, the option with value set to "" is removed and the one with value 1 is selected.

Comment: Show the controller code

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue. Are you by any chance hovering your mouse over one of the options and then tabbing away? In some browsers this will cause the option that was hovered over to be selected.